# Use App button on facebook page is not opening the app link on both appstore/playstore

Tags: android, ios, facebook, applinks

I've implemented the facebook "Use App" button on the facebook page and I'm trying to redirect the user to the appstore link or the playstore link depending on the User's device.

But I get blank page instead of taking me the playstore when I open it on my android device. How can I get it to open respective app stores when I click on "Use app" button?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta property="og:image" content="example.png" />
        <meta property="al:ios:url" content="myapplication://" />
        <meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="11" />
        <meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="myapp" />
        <meta property="al:android:url" content="myapplication://?U=">
        <meta property="al:android:package" content="com.myapp.myapp">
        <meta property="al:android:app_name" content="myapp">
        <meta property="og:title" content="myapp" />
        <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
        <meta property="al:web:should_fallback" content="false" />

</head><body>

</body></html>
```

Comment: What are the URLs you have used?

Comment: @IshitaSinha These are URLs I've specified in the app.